# Is there any performance difference between these 3 queries

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `t1` and `t2` as below:

```
create table t1(
  id int primary key,
  name varchar(10),
  desc varchar(500)
);

create table t2(
  id int primary key,
  tid int foreign key references t1(id),
  code varchar(10)
);
```

Now I want to query some data from `t1` where it has related record in `t2`,so I wrote the following three queries:

```
-- query1,using in with hard code inside it,n might be more than 100
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id IN(tid1,tid2,....tidn);

-- query2,using in with subquery 
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id IN(SELECT tid FROM t2);

-- query3,using join
SELECT t1.* FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id=t2.tid;
```

Now I am wondering which one has the best query performance,suppose the version of `MySQL` is **5.1**(also is it has something to do with the version?),
thanks in advance!

I have tested it myself,and I found it with something to do with the data size,different size will give different result,so I ask it here

Comment: Err why don't you test them against the data only you have access to? AND run explain plans..

Comment: @P.Salmon Since I want to know the analysis in theory,thanks

Comment: Ahh you want an explanation of how the optimiser works..

Comment: @P.Salmon I have tested it myself,and I found it with something to do with the data size,different size will give different result,so I ask it here

Comment: @P.Salmon,yeah,that's what I want to know

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure for the performance but the last one is the better one as most of database have a limit of x elements in IN CLAUSE. I think it is the fastest as well but it is better to test to confirm that.

Comment: I am using `MySQL` and it has not limit for `IN()`

Comment: @lucumt:it has... enough people can show you an example   in fact you can test it yourself if you have 'a lot of rows' in t2.